# Selenium + Headless Chrome, YouTube doesn't connect to account after credentials submitted

Tags: python, selenium, chrome-web-driver

For education purposes, I decided to build some automation script on YouTube (that cannot be achieved through the API because of some channel switch involved).

I'm using Selenium and Headless Chrome. 
My script is working fine when I set everything to `headless-false`, but that's because I'm able to import `user-data-dir`, which allows me to avoid the login loop I come through in the login process.

So, I started monitoring what happens with headless-false when I don't import my data, and it seems that it doesn't want to login for whatever reasons.

Problem isn't with me not being able to enter my credentials in the login and password fields, but just in YouTube not logging me in after the credentials have been sent.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument("user-data-dir=Admin$ /Users/Admin/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile\ 30")
options.add_argument("window-size=1440,900")
options.add_argument('headless-false')

# launching the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

# entering credentials
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[2]/ytd-button-renderer/a/paper-button/yt-formatted-string').click()

time.sleep(1)
email = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type=email]')
email.send_keys('myemail@gmail.com')
print("Email entered")

driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()
time.sleep(1)

password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type=password]')
password.send_keys('mypassword')
print("Password entered")
driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
print("Logged in!")
```

For some reason, when it goes back to YouTube after the login, the channel is still not logged in. I tried many different ways, like trying to go through youtube mobile site, logging on gmail first and then accessing YouTube, but there is nothing to do.

I also know that using `sleep ()` isn't a good way to do those things, and that I could use some `implicit wait` instead, but I want to fix the main issue first before tweaking the whole thing.

Comment: Where are you exactly stuck?

Comment: In fact, once the login button is pressed, for some reason it doesn't login. It goes back to YouTube homepage still showing the login button while I'm supposed to be logged on. 

I have different channels on this YouTube account, and that might be the reason for the bug, but it's not normal at all that the browser isn't showing the channel selection "popup".

Comment: your code is works, try manual login to see if your account not blocked

Comment: I think what's causing the problem is the fact that I have channels on the youtube account. But normally, it should at least show me the channel popup, but it's not. 

https://imgur.com/a/HJDkaSe (that screenshot is what I get on normal chrome, not on webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

I think it wont work, because youtube sees the login process being done from a headless browser/selenium webdriver and denies it.
Same issue with www.google.com (see https://gist.github.com/ikegami-yukino/51b247080976cb41fe93)